# Cubic interpolation in Pandas raises ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 3, got 0+0

Tags: python, resampling

Using the below weekly dataset, I want to resample to monthly data with cubic conversion.

```
Period       Values    
20-Jan-89   3  
27-Jan-89   4  
3-Feb-89    2  
10-Feb-89   5  
17-Feb-89   3  
24-Feb-89   5  
3-Mar-89    5  
10-Mar-89   6  
17-Mar-89   4  
24-Mar-89   5  
31-Mar-89   7  
7-Apr-89    6  
14-Apr-89   6  
21-Apr-89   4  
28-Apr-89   7  
5-May-89    5  
12-May-89   6  
19-May-89   5  
26-May-89   7  
2-Jun-89    7
```

I used the code appended below,

```
q= pd.Series(df[series], index=df.index)
m = q.resample('M').interpolate(method='cubic')
```

but I get error

**ValueError: The number of derivatives at boundaries does not match: expected 3, got 0+0**